# PGP Key Server and Bouncy Castle OpenPGP API Java

Tags: java, bouncycastle, gnupg, pgp, openpgp

Is it possible (and then how) to communicate with PGP Key Server, like https://pgp.mit.edu or http://keyserver.pgp.com or private key server: upload a key, search for a key, download a key etc. - using Bouncy Castle OpenPGP API on Java?

Is there any open sourced PGP key server implementation on Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware Bouncy Castle has support for key server communication,  but wouldn't consider this an issue.

The most widely spread protocol used for key server communication is [HKP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-shaw-openpgp-hkp-00), built upon HTTP. Implementing the protocol as a client does not really require any large libraries, for basic operations some simple HTTP requests will be sufficient.

As an example, the [specification proposal lists following requests](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-shaw-openpgp-hkp-00#section-3.4):

> Search for all keys containing the string "dshaw":

> ```
> http://keys.example.com:11371/pks/lookup?search=dshaw&op=index
> ```

> Get key 0x99242560 (32-bit key ID):

> ```
> http://keys.example.com:11371/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x99242560
> ```

Uploading new keys is a simple as [sending an HTTP POST request](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-shaw-openpgp-hkp-00#section-4):

> Keyserver submissions are done via a HTTP POST URL.  Specifically,
> the abs_path (see [2], section 3.2) is set to "/pks/add", and the key
> data is provided via HTTP POST as specified in [2], section 8.3, and
> [3], section 8.2.3. [...]